# Multi-line watermark overlapping issue

Tags: java, itext, watermark

I'm trying to develop a watermark stamper that supports i18n and multi-line watermarks. I am able to create it, but the problem is that the watermark is overlapping the text from the previous line as shown in picture below.[image]

My watermark text has the following content: `123\n456\n789`. What I'm willing to do is set the watermark without overlapping the lines. How can I do that? Below is part of my code:

**WaterMarkStamper.java**

```
public void insertWaterMark() throws Exception {
    final File pdfFile = this.getFile();
    if (pdfFile != null && pdfFile.exists()) {
        PdfReader reader = null;
        PdfStamper stamp = null;
        try {
            reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile.getAbsolutePath());
            final int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            temp = this.getNewFile();
            // Create a stamper that will copy the document to a new file
            stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(temp));
            PdfContentByte over;
            int pageIndex = 1;
            while (pageIndex <= n) {
                over = stamp.getOverContent(pageIndex);
                this.addWatermark(wmVO, reader, over, pageIndex, position);
                pageIndex++;
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            WaterMarkStamper.logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        } finally {
            if (stamp != null) {
                stamp.close();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void addWatermark(final WaterMarkVO wmVo, final PdfReader reader, final PdfContentByte contentByte, final Integer pageIndex) throws Exception {
    final Rectangle page = reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(pageIndex);

    // This is where the magic happens
    final Image img = wmVo.getImage(contentByte);

    // Get margins
    final int leftMargin = wmVo.getLeftMargin();
    final int topMargin = wmVo.getTopMargin();
    final int rightMargin = wmVo.getRightMargin();
    final int bottomMargin = wmVo.getBottomMargin();

    // Absolute position
    final Point pt = this.getImageInsertionPoint(img, page, leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);
    img.setAbsolutePosition((float) pt.getX(), (float) pt.getY());

    // Add image
    contentByte.addImage(img);
}
```

**WaterMarkVO.java**

```
public Image getImage(final PdfContentByte contentByte) throws Exception {
    final Paragraph paragraph = this.getParagraph();
    final Rectangle paragraphRectangle = this.getParagraphRectangle();
    final float paragraphHeight = paragraphRectangle.getHeight();
    final float paragraphWidth = paragraphRectangle.getWidth();

    final PdfTemplate xObject = contentByte.createTemplate(paragraphWidth, paragraphHeight + this.getFontSize());
    final ColumnText column = new ColumnText(xObject);
    column.setSimpleColumn(0, 0, paragraphWidth, paragraphHeight);
    column.setExtraParagraphSpace(0f);
    column.addElement(paragraph);
    column.go();

    final Image img = Image.getInstance(xObject);
    final int rotation = this.getRotation();
    img.setRotationDegrees(rotation);
    return img;
}

public Paragraph getParagraph() throws Exception {
    final FontSelector fontSelector = this.getFontSelector();
    final String text = "123\n456\n789";
    this.fontSelectorPhrase = fontSelector.process(text);
    final Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(this.fontSelectorPhrase);

    return paragraph;
}

public Rectangle getParagraphRectangle() throws Exception {
    final String text = "123\n456\n789";
    final float fontSize = this.getFontSize();
    float paragraphWidth = 0f;
    float paragraphHeight = 0f;
    float leading = 0f;
    final String[] lines = text.split("\n");

    List<Chunk> chunks = this.fontSelectorPhrase.getChunks();
    for(Chunk c : chunks) {
        int indexer = 0;
        final Paragraph p = new Paragraph(" ", c.getFont());
        do {
            final float currentLineWidth = c.getFont().getBaseFont().getWidthPoint(" " + lines[indexer] + " ", fontSize);
            final float currentLineHeight = c.getFont().getBaseFont().getAscentPoint(lines[indexer], fontSize) + c.getFont().getBaseFont().getDescentPoint(lines[indexer], fontSize);
            final float curentLineLeading = p.getLeading();

            paragraphWidth = currentLineWidth > paragraphWidth ? currentLineWidth : paragraphWidth;
            paragraphHeight = currentLineHeight > paragraphHeight ? currentLineHeight : paragraphHeight;
            leading = currentLineLeading > leading ? currentLineLeading : leading; 
            indexer++;
        } while (indexer < lines.length);
    }

    paragraphHeight += leading / lines.length;

    return new Rectangle(paragraphWidth, paragraphHeight);
}

public FontSelector getFontSelector() throws Exception {
    // Adding fonts to support i18n
    FontSelector fontSelector = new FontSelector();
    fontSelector.addFont(new Font(BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED))); // Does not support some turkish glyphs 
    fontSelector.addFont(new Font(BaseFont.createFont("helvetica.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED))); // Support some turkish glyphs
    return fontSelector;
}
```

Obviously, I've hidden part of the code that was unnecessary. In this example I'm not using special characters on the watermark, but my code must attend this requirement (I followed what was stated on p378 in "iText in Action 2nd edition").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [mkl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35037711/2836945) and [Paulo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35033394/2836945) I could note some mistakes on my calculus. Below is the code that is now working for me:

**WaterMarkVO.java**

```
public Image getImage(final PdfContentByte contentByte) throws Exception {
    final Paragraph paragraph = this.getParagraph();
    final Rectangle paragraphRectangle = this.getParagraphRectangle();
    final float paragraphHeight = paragraphRectangle.getHeight();
    final float paragraphWidth = paragraphRectangle.getWidth();

    final PdfTemplate xObject = contentByte.createTemplate(paragraphWidth, paragraphHeight + this.getFontSize());
    final ColumnText column = new ColumnText(xObject);
    column.setSimpleColumn(0, 0, paragraphWidth, paragraphHeight);
    column.setExtraParagraphSpace(0f);
    column.addElement(paragraph);
    column.go();

    final Image img = Image.getInstance(xObject);
    final int rotation = this.getRotation();
    img.setRotationDegrees(rotation);
    return img;
}

public Rectangle getParagraphRectangle(final WatermarkPosition position, Paragraph para) throws Exception {
    int numberOfLines = 1;
    float paragraphWidth = 0f;
    float paragraphHeight = 0f;
    float leading = 0f;
    float chunkFontSize = 0f;
    float currentChunkWidth = 0f;
    float currentChunkHeight = 0f;
    Font f = null;
    BaseFont bf = null;
    String content = null;

    List<Chunk> chunks = this.fontSelectorPhrase.getChunks();
    for(Chunk c : chunks) {
        f = c.getFont();
        bf = f.getBaseFont();
        content = c.getContent();
        chunkFontSize = f.getSize();
        currentChunkWidth = bf.getWidthPoint(" " + content + " ", chunkFontSize);

        currentChunkHeight = chunkFontSize + bf.getAscentPoint(content, chunkFontSize) - bf.getDescentPoint(content, chunkFontSize);

        if(!c.getContent().contains(System.getProperty("line.separator"))) {
            paragraphWidth += currentChunkWidth > paragraphWidth ? currentChunkWidth : paragraphWidth;
        } else {
            paragraphWidth = currentChunkWidth;
            numberOfLines++;
        }

        paragraphHeight = currentChunkHeight > paragraphHeight ? currentChunkHeight : paragraphHeight;

        leading = chunkFontSize > leading ? chunkFontSize : leading; 
    }

    para.setLeading(leading);

    paragraphHeight += (leading * numberOfLines);

    return new Rectangle(paragraphWidth, paragraphHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `Paragraph` leading is insufficient. Set the leading the same size as the font or 1.25 for a pleasant typographic effect.

Answer (score 0):

You calculate the `currentLineHeight` to be the **sum** of `Ascent` and `Descent`:

```
final float currentLineHeight = c.getFont().getBaseFont().getAscentPoint(lines[indexer], fontSize) + c.getFont().getBaseFont().getDescentPoint(lines[indexer], fontSize);
```

But the `Descent` is not positive but zero or even negative, cf. the JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * Gets the descent of a <CODE>String</CODE> in points. The descent will always be
 * less than or equal to zero even if all the characters have an higher descent.
 * @param text the <CODE>String</CODE> to get the descent of
 * @param fontSize the size of the font
 * @return the descent in points
 */
public float getDescentPoint(String text, float fontSize)
```

Thus, most likely you need the **difference** here (or the sum of the absolute values):

```
final float currentLineHeight = c.getFont().getBaseFont().getAscentPoint(lines[indexer], fontSize) - c.getFont().getBaseFont().getDescentPoint(lines[indexer], fontSize);
```

(This at least will calculate the rectangle correctly, in particular when you start creating watermarks with characters with relevant descents.)